# How to access laptop built-in fingerprint scanner in c#?

Tags: c#

My c# windows application using external USB fingerprint scanner for capture finger print, i want to access laptop built-in fingerprint scanner instead of external USB scanner.
is it possible? how to access that? please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to figure out exactly what manufacturer makes the scanner  and what model it is, then go to the manufacturer's web site and see what tools they provide. If there aren't any on the web site, contact the manufacturer.

Note that it's very likely that the SDK for the scanner (a) is available only if you sign a non-disclosure agreement and (b) costs money. If you're lucky, the manufacturer's SDK complies with the BioAPI standard, which will make it easier (note: not "easy") to use your code with scanners from other vendors.